# Apply a random class to every element specified

Tags: jquery, css, random

I am trying to add a random class to even < li > element within my #container div

Here is my code:

```
$( "#container li" ).each(  

  $().ready(function() {

        $("#container li:random").addClass("one");
        $("#container li:random").addClass("two");
        $("#container li:random").addClass("three");

    })
    );
```

The problem is that I have ten < li > elements and I want each of these elements to receive one of the three possible classes in a random fashion.

However my code above only assignes three < li > elements with the classes leaving the remaining seven < li > elements class-less.

I have tried other snippets of code but none of which randomly apply a list of classes to ALL elements specified.

I have tried snippets from this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911855/adding-randomly-chosen-class-to-html-tag-using-jquery) but none of which produce the desired result of making sure all elements get a random class.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: post more code, or better still, make a jsfiddle.com out of it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an array of classes and then assign a random class from that array to each element matching a selector like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["one", "two", "three"];

    $("#container li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
});
```

If you want to ensure that each class is only used once, you can remove it from the array when it is used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["one", "two", "three"];

    $("#container li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass( classes.splice( ~~(Math.random()*classes.length), 1 )[0] );
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much - worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: What would be the way to be sure that each class is set once. Your code can set the class for more than one element.

Comment: @karadayi You would want to remove each class from the array as you use it. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @karadayi Example added, using splice to remove the class from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
$( function (){
    $( "#container li" ).each( function (){
        var rng = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
        var rndmClass = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ];

        $(this).addClass( rndmClass[rng]);
    });
});
```

The corresponding HTML DOM might look like:

```
ul#container
    li
    li
    li
```

Effectively, I took the onload statement and tucked the .each function inside of it. Secondly, I added a function(){} inside of the each() statement. This function picks a number at random from 0-4; each number corresponds to a class in the rndmClass array, and adds that class to each list item found in your #container.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little jquery plugin that might work for you. Check it out:
https://github.com/cjthedizzy/randomClassJS