# Apply a random class to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apply a random class to every element specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686592/apply-a-random-class-to-every-element-specified)

Is it possible to get all 'a' elements on a page and apply the class either '.pink', '.blue', or '.yellow' RANDOMLY to every a element with javascript? I want to have different colored links on my page but equally randomized. I don't have a clue how I'd do this so I don't have any scripts to provide.

Answer (score 3):

When you use jQuery as stated in your tags, this is a possible solution:

```
// when document is loaded
$(document).ready(function () {

    // set classes
    var classes     = new Array ('pink', 'blue', 'green');

    // calculate length once, as this will never change
    var length      = classes.length;

    // select all a-tags
    var links       = $('a');

    // loop through all a-tags and apply color randomly
    $.each( links, function(key, value) {
        // get random value/class-name from array and add it using the addClass function
        $(value).addClass( classes[ Math.floor ( Math.random() * length ) ] );
    });

});
```

The comments should make clear what it does.

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/b7xv8/)

Comment: Did you really mean `$.each`?

Comment: Yeah, is something wrong with it? :)

Comment: Why not `$('a').each(function() { ... $(this).addClass(...) ... }`? That's the beauty of jQuery.

Comment: What would be the way to be sure that the color is set once? Your code is fine but it set sometimes the same color on more than one element.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random()` will return a random floating-point number between zero and one. To convert it into an array index, multiply it by the size of the array and take `Math.floor` to round it down:

```
var arr = ['red','green','blue'];
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

alert(arr[idx]);
```

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 2):

You can put your classes in array and then loop through "A" tags and assign random index (with Math.random()) to each one:

```
var colorClasses = ['pink', 'blue', 'yellow'];
$("a").each(function(e){
    classIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorClasses.length);
    $(this).addClass(colorClasses[classIndex]);
});​
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ALngA/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ['pink', 'blue', 'yellow']
$('a').each(function () {
  var rand = ~~(Math.random() * colors.length)
  $(this).addClass(colors[rand])
})
```