# Apply the same random class to every element specified

Tags: jquery, css

I have been working with the answer provided here:
[Apply a random class to every element specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686592/apply-a-random-class-to-every-element-specified)

However, I would like it to select from the classes listed then apply the randomly selected class to three items.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var classes = ["c4kdarkerBlue", "c4korange", "c4kyellow", "c4kyellow", "c4kpink", "c4kpurple", "c4kgreen", "c4kred"];

    $(".instructorDetails h3, .instructorDetails h4, .instructorDetails h5").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
});
```

The above code chooses a random class, but applies a different one to each item instead of the same class to all three.

I need the h3, h4, and h5 to all have the same colour - randomly selected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define the random class outside of the each() loop and apply it inside as you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create the random number inside `.each` it will generate a new one for each element. You should do it like;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var classes = ["c4kdarkerBlue", "c4korange", "c4kyellow", "c4kyellow", "c4kpink", "c4kpurple", "c4kgreen", "c4kred"],
        randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);

    $(".instructorDetails h3, .instructorDetails h4, .instructorDetails h5").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[randNum]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Osoner - that's perfect!