# jQuery mouseover doesn't work as expected on document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have my own cursor only displayed over certain images with a certain class.

I've already written a few lines for that.

Here is my code:

```
function registerCursorHoverEffect() {
    if (!isTouch()) {
        const el = document.body;
        var cursorDiv = document.createElement("div");
        cursorDiv.setAttribute("id", "cursor");
        cursorDiv.setAttribute("class", "light-spot light-spot--cursor light-spot--center-center light-spot--color-red light-spot--filled light-spot--outside");
        el.before(cursorDiv);

        document.getElementById("cursor").innerHTML = '<svg class="cursor-main" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" viewport="0 0 100 100" style="stroke: white; fill:white;font-size:300px; z-index: 9999999;position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 40px; bottom: 0;"><path d="M59.71,31.29l-10-10a1,1,0,0,0-1.42,1.42L56.59,31H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H56.59l-8.3,8.29a1,1,0,0,0,0,1.42,1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0l10-10A1,1,0,0,0,59.71,31.29Z"/></svg>';
        var cursorDivAppend = document.createElement("div");
        cursorDivAppend.setAttribute("id", "cursor-append");
        cursorDivAppend.setAttribute("class", "cursor-append");
        el.before(cursorDivAppend);

        // Mousemove
        $(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
            if($('.col-3:hover').length != 0) {
                const appendScale = 1
                var destinationX = event.pageX;
                var destinationY = event.pageY;
                var transformScale = `translate(calc(${destinationX}px - 50%), calc(${destinationY}px - 50%)) scale(${appendScale})`
                $('#cursor').css('transform', transformScale);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The following screenshot shows what is generated when you hover over an image with a certain class:

[image]

The critical part of it all is here:

```
        // Mousemove
        $(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
            if($('.col-3:hover').length != 0) {
                const appendScale = 1
                var destinationX = event.pageX;
                var destinationY = event.pageY;
                var transformScale = `translate(calc(${destinationX}px - 50%), calc(${destinationY}px - 50%)) scale(${appendScale})`
                $('#cursor').css('transform', transformScale);
            }
        })
```

`event.pageX` should always give me the current mouse position of the `$(document)` and not of the event itself. Exactly the same for `event.pageY`. But I always get the current position of the event and I don't know why.

Can somebody help me please?

UPDATE:

However, the width of the cursor element hinders me because I get the coordinates of the `$ (documents)`. The event is only triggered when I am outside the cursor.
Here is a screenshot and to clarify the problem:
[image]

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. If it isn't giving you the value expect, what value is it giving you instead, and what is telling you that that value is incorrect?

Comment: The value is completely okay. The mouseover only reacts as soon as I am out of the width of the cursor. But I always want to get the mouse coordinates for the document and not from the event. That's the problem here. I will update my answer soon for clarification.

Comment: So, you're saying the event doesn't fire at all until you move the mouse out of a certain area?

Comment: Yes that is correct. After I first hovered out of the width of the element, the cursor moves to the desired position

Comment: What calls `registerCursorHoverEffect`? Are you sure this if statement isn't hindering your logic? `if($('.col-3:hover').length != 0) {`?

Comment: This function is only declared in `$(document).ready`

Comment: `if($('.col-3:hover').length != 0) {` is the specific class i would like to call. The cursor should only be seen in this class with `$(document)` mouse coordinates. This is working because i only can see the cursor when i hover over the area with this class. But the cursor is laggy and not working propertly.

Comment: my concern is, this event fires all the time. If it's not firing when you expect it to, it actually is, and that if statement is preventing it from doing what you expect it to.

Comment: When you *show* the cursor, you are no longer hovering over the element, because the cursor is instead there. That's what causes the flashing and such.

Comment: The Event IS firing all time. But only when i get out of the specific width of the cursor element.
The only issue is that the cursor is laggy as hell because it didnt get out of the area with every mousemove

Comment: Right, but the problem is you are preventing the event from working, when the cursor is visible.... but you only want it to work while the cursor is visible...

Comment: Ah okay i understand.
How did i get it to work then? Because i want to hide the cursor until it gets to this area

Comment: What I'm saying is your current solution to this is flawed. It can't work that way, you can't say "don't process events unless "EXAMPLE" is hovered over, and then stick an element between the mouse and "EXAMPLE". that's never going to work. So you need to separate the concerns here. Upon entering "EXAMPLE", take note of the position of that element and create a bounding area. Continue processing events until the mouse moves outside of that bounding area. Don't rely on :hover length

Comment: By bounding area, i mean define coordinates for a square, and when outside of those coordinates, you know it's time to hide the cursor, else you're moving the cursor with the mouse.

Comment: You may also need to account for the possibility of the page scrolling, but chances are the mouse will move outside of the element on scroll pretty fast anyway

Comment: Can I make the whole thing dynamic without defining fixed coordinates?

Comment: The difficulty is detecting when the mouse leaves the target area. Entering is easy

Comment: Try… take note of the mouse position when it enters, and from that point you know it can move a specific distance in x or y before it has left the area.

Comment: And how do I get the mouse position as soon as I move exactly over this element? Somehow I have to query the whole thing, but I don't know how ...

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have my own cursor only displayed over certain images with a certain class.

You can do that only with css,

```css
.cursors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cursors > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cursors > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
.cursors > div:hover {
  opacity: 0.25;
} 
.png {
  cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/heart.png"), auto;
}
.gif {
cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png"), auto;
}
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Equal to rotateZ(45deg) */
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursors">
  <div><img  class="png rotated"src="https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/images/patreon_btn.png"/> </div>
  <div class="gif">GIF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. I already tried this with the `cursor` variant. Unfortunately, my SVG and my light point are not displayed correctly there. Otherwise, I still think your answer is very good .

I'm just looking for a jQuery or JavaScript variant

Comment: It won't work with SVG. only with Base 64 PNG and PNG. I think you are overcomplicating it with javascript. BTW here are some custom cursor examples: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/31/custom-cursor-effects/

Comment: Thank i will have a look at it.
Problem here is that i will make the colors randomize. So that the color of the cursor is not just orange. It can be green or black for example too.

Comment: Just add more classes, let me edit it

Comment: check it now, over gif :)

Comment: Can i change this gif evertime i reload the page? For example the happy and heart emoji will be random picked? When yes then there is a solution way just over css for me.

Comment: to do that I would create an array of possible classes, and shuffle everytime page reloads, and assign to selected tags

Comment: Then i will take a look at that with PHP. Thank you sir.

Comment: You can do with javascript, check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686592/apply-a-random-class-to-every-element-specified

Comment: I already got something:
`const color = colorNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorNames.length)]`. `colorNames` is an array with colors in it.

Comment: dont make it const because it will not change, make it var.

Comment: yeah my bad. I changed it.

Comment: Glad I helped, have nice day :)

Comment: BTW, can you mark as accepted answer. It will encurage others to answer in future.